# When iterating through controls on a form, how can I identify particular buttons?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to make some changes to a TaskDialog before it is shown to the user.  It's fairly simple to use Windows API calls to work with each of the controls on the dialog box.  I need to be more sure which button I have found.  I would have expected to find a place where I could read the result the button would give if pressed.

in other words, if I pressed a button that would cause a return value (in Delphi, it's called a modal result) of 100, I would have expected there to be an API call I could call to find out what the button's "return value" would be.  I haven't yet found any such call.

I don't want to rely on the button text..

Here's what I have so far.

```
function EnumWindowsProcToFindDlgControls(hWindow: HWND; _param:LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  sClassName:string;
  hBMP:THandle;
  i:integer;
begin
  SetLength(sClassName, MAX_PATH);
  GetClassName(hWindow, PChar(sClassName), MAX_PATH);
  SetLength(sClassName, StrLen(PChar(sClassName)));

  if sClassName='Button' then
    begin    
      // always 0...
      i:=GetDlgCtrlID(hWindow);

      if (i=100) or (i=102) then
        begin
          hBmp := LoadImage(HInstance, 'DISA', IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE or LR_LOADTRANSPARENT );

          SendMessage(hWindow, BM_SETIMAGE, WPARAM(IMAGE_BITMAP), LPARAM(hBmp));
        end;
    end;

  // keep looking
  Result:=true;
end;

procedure TForm2.TaskDialog1DialogConstructed(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnumChildWindows(TaskDialog1.Handle, @EnumWindowsProcToFindDlgControls, 0);
end;
```

I suspect it's not entirely "respectable" to do things like this with a dialog.

This is a Delphi 10 Win32 application using Delphi's VCL TTaskDialog component which is a wrapper around Windows task dialog feature.  before it's shown, the OnConstructed event fires, executing this code.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I didn't read your code, but you can identify particular buttons by their ID. You just have to know the ID of the controls you want to change.

Comment: It seems that the ID is always 0 when built by the task dialog routine in windows.

Comment: FWIW, you can replace `SetLength(sClassName, StrLen(PChar(sClassName)));` and similar code by `sClassName := PChar(sClassName);`. That will achieve the same.

Comment: Mysterious "directuihwnd" interface... Very inconsiderate that the controls don't have IDs. Almost like the VCL implementation of assigning window handles to IDs.. utterly useless..

Comment: You can expect anything you write to fail on future versions. These dialogs are already customisable through supported means. You don't need to meddle with them.

Comment: "Customizable through supported means"?  How can I choose the icon for each command link?  Naturally, I would prefer to use more respectable methods...

Comment: Your program will break on a future version of Windows. Does that bother you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I dislike using techniques of this kind in case that happens.  Your comment some time ago said it was already customizable "via supported means"...how is that done?

Comment: Customizable in many ways. Not that way. Options as I see it. Use the dirty hack you eye up in this question. Write a bespoke dialog. Stick with the default command link icons. I personally like the final option. Whose driving the development? Your non programming boss?

Comment: Yes, those are the options we see too.  The team needs to decide whether this technique that is sufficiently respectable and reliable.  I see it works on Vista-10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Win32 buttons do not have "return values", which is why there is no API to retrieve such a value from them. What you are thinking of is strictly a VCL feature.

In Win32 API terms, a button can have a control ID, and in the case of `MessageBox()`, for example, standard ID values like `IDOK`, `IDCANCEL`, etc are assigned to the dialog buttons.  When a button is clicked and the dialog is closed, the button's control ID is used as the function return value.

But task dialogs do not use control IDs, which is why you do not see any assigned to the dialog buttons.

To identify a particular task dialog button, I can think of two ways:

1. during child enumeration, retrieve each button's caption text ([`GetWindowText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx)), and compare that to captions you are interested in. Just know that the standard buttons (from the `TTaskDialog.CommonButtons` property) use localized text, which does not make this a well-suited option for locating standard buttons unless you have control over the app's locale settings.
2. send the dialog a [`TDM_ENABLE_BUTTON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787505.aspx) message to temporarily disable the desired button that has a given ID, then enumerate the dialog's controls until you find a disabled child window (using [`IsWindowEnabled()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646303.aspx)), and then re-enable the control.  You can then manipulate the found window as needed.

   For [Task Dialog messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486053.aspx) and [Task Dialog Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486054.aspx) that operate on buttons (like [`TDN_BUTTON_CLICKED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787477.aspx), which triggers the `TTaskDialog.OnButtonClicked` event), the standard buttons use IDs like `IDOK`, `IDCANCEL`, etc while custom buttons (from the `TTaskDialog.Buttons` property) use their `ModalResult` property as their ID.

   You can send `TDM_ENABLE_BUTTON` directly via `SendMessage()` for standard buttons, or via the `TTaskDialogBaseButtonItem.Enabled` property for custom buttons.

For #2, this works when I try it:

```
uses
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

function FindDisabledDlgControl(hWindow: HWND; _param: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
type
  PHWND = ^HWND;
begin
  if not IsWindowEnabled(hWindow) then
  begin
    PHWND(_param)^ := hWindow;
    Result := False;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm2.TaskDialog1DialogConstructed(Sender: TObject);
var
  hButton: HWND;
begin
  // common tcbOk button
  SendMessage(TaskDialog1.Handle, TDM_ENABLE_BUTTON, IDOK, 0);
  hButton := 0;
  EnumChildWindows(TaskDialog1.Handle, @FindDisabledDlgControl, LPARAM(@hButton));
  SendMessage(TaskDialog1.Handle, TDM_ENABLE_BUTTON, IDOK, 1);
  if hButton <> 0 then
  begin
    // use hButton as needed...
  end;

  // custom button
  TaskDialog1.Buttons[0].Enabled := False;
  hButton := 0;
  EnumChildWindows(TaskDialog1.Handle, @FindDisabledDlgControl, LPARAM(@hButton));
  TaskDialog1.Buttons[0].Enabled := True;
  if hButton <> 0 then
  begin
    // use hButton as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and creative answer (works famously)!  This is much better than relying on the button text (not an acceptable situation for us).  I'll be sure to try it on our minimum system too...   Learned some good stuff doing this...

Comment: What if there already is a disabled button in the list of controls, How would you know you have the correct window?